# Why OBJLoader not working with three.js ? es6

Tags: reactjs, three.js, objloader

I would like to load an object ".obj" with three.js.

My code :

```js
/********** Imports **********/
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import OBJLoader from 'three-obj-loader';
OBJLoader('THREE');

export class Satellites extends PureComponent {

  componentDidMount() {
    // Satellite Sphere
    this.geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 10, 32, 32 );
    // Texture
    this.texture = new THREE.OBJLoader().load
    ('textures/Satellite.obj',
      texture => {
        this.sat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: this.texture } );
        this.sphere = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, this.sat );
        this.props.scene.add( this.sphere );
      }
    )
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Error :

```
Attempted import error: 'OBJLoader' is not exported from 'three' (imported as 'THREE').
```

So I use this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-obj-loader)
I add this line *import OBJLoader from 'three-obj-loader';*

But nothing... I still have the same error with this import !

More details : https://github.com/SolenneD/earth-react

**Scene.js** and **Satellite.js** *(this is the first version so not this code but there is a texture .obj)*

Thanks for help.

Comment: Yes, `OBJLoader` is no part of the `three.js` core. You can try to transform `OBJLoader` to a module by yourself or you use one of the existing `npm` packages. However, the last approach is sometimes problematic since the packages are not always well maintained. What error occurs if you use `three-object-loader`? Your current shared code is unfortunately not helpful in this context.

Comment: I have edit my question, thanks !

Comment: If you are using the `npm` package, it should be sufficient to call `new OBJLoader()`. Notice the missing `THREE` namespace.

Comment: I already called `new OBJLoader ()` with `this.texture = new THREE.OBJLoader().load`.
With my code (I have edited with the import) I have the same error : 
`Attempted import error: 'OBJLoader' is not exported from 'three' (imported as 'THREE').`

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the problematic code as a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/)? Can you at least update your repository with the code using `OBJLoader`? I have checked your repo but [Satellites.js](https://github.com/SolenneD/earth-react/blob/master/src/components/Satellites.js) seems to represent a previous version.

Comment: since release 101 of the library there is a script that generates modules out of example/js files. https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/15518

Comment: @Mugen87 Done ! :)

Comment: @gaitat, Thanks, I'm going to have a look.

Comment: I was able to solve the runtime error with this guide: https://github.com/sohamkamani/three-object-loader/issues/10#issuecomment-316981216

Comment: Thanks, I push on my repo. Now, the problem is `Cannot create property 'OBJLoader' on string 'THREE'` What does it mean ?